# How to resume loop when wget returns error 404 - Bash

Tags: linux, bash, wget

I am trying to write a simple script that will download a file for me, but I do not know the exact url. There is an id in the middle of the url that I want to increment until i actually get the right id. The problem is the starting point is incorrect and wget returns a 404 Error and then the loop doesn't continue.

How can I get the loop to try again with the new id?

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/sh

id=7887902
urla="https://firsthalfofurl"
urlb="secondhalfofurl.pdf"

url=$urla$id$urlb

for i in {1..5};
do
    wget --user uname --password pass $url;
    id=$((id+1));
    url=$urla$id$urlb
done
```

I also tried adding || true after $url in the wget command, and that did not work.

Comment: How are you running the script? The script, as it appears, should repeat `wget` 5 times, even if `wget` fails each time.

Comment: In the shell I type sh ./scriptname. I assumed that would be how it would run as well but it seems like the 404 error from the first iteration is causing the script to exit the loop rather than try again with the new value.

Comment: Do you have set -e set?  That seems likely since "normally" the loop would continue even if wget failed.  You might want to check out http://serverfault.com/questions/143445/what-does-set-e-do-and-why-might-it-be-considered-dangerous for some more discussion about it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
wget --user uname --password pass $url || true;
```

This way, if wget fails, the result of that line is still zero and your script continues.

Comment: hmm...wouldn't that help only when the `e` option is set? It's not the default behaviour I think.

Comment: I tried that before posting. This is the error I get:                                                  2015-04-18 17:04:42 ERROR 404: Not Found

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found a solution. It's not perfect because the result is an infinite loop that can only be terminated by ctrl -c. Here is my new code.

```
#!/bin/sh


id=8057270
urla="firsthalfofurl"
urlb="secondhalfofurl.pdf"

checka="$(ls -l | wc -l)"
checkb="$(ls -l | wc -l)"
url=$urla$id$urlb
update () {
    id=$((id+1));
    url=$urla$id$urlb;
    checkb="$(ls -l | wc -l)";
}


yes () {

    #check to see if the number of files in the folder has increased.
    if [ $checkb -gt $checka ]; then
        #this will show up on every successive loop so if I let it run overnight I will know if the file has been found. Not really necessary.
        sleep 3;
        echo File Found;
        sleep 1;
    fi;
    update;

    wget --user username --password pass $url;
    trap yes EXIT
    yes
}

yes
```

Answer (score -1):

You should double quote all your `$url`'s. Since we can't see what `first-` and `secondhalfofurl` are, there may be critical characters in there that spoil your command.

E.g.

```
wget --user uname --password pass "$url"
```

Comment: They are double quoted when I create the variables. I added double quotes around $url in the wget call and it still did not work

Comment: and what's about `url=$urla$id$urlb`?

Comment: I know the code works if I start with a correct id value because I do know the id for one file and it works if that id is set as the iniital value for $id.